# restricting a codedom compiled assembly

Tags: security, codedom

i've written a plugin manager for my app , it utilizes codedom to compile c# code into a class library and instanciate its types.
it works perfectly , and now i wish to restrict the permissions on the compiled assembly.unfortunatly i dont know how to do so.
as far as i understand i should use CompilerParameters.Evidence in some way, but it is unclear to me of how.
for te sake of clearity , i dont wish to simply categorize the assmbly as a certain zone, i want to limit it to a permission set that is passed as an argument in the plugin managers constructor. i also would like to mention that i do not load the assembly into a new appdomin , it is executed on the same domain as the rest of the application.

thanks.

Comment: Exactly 1 year later I have the same question. Did you have any luck finding an answer?

Comment: How to do this with .NET Framework 4.0? CompilerParameters.Evidence is deprecated now.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

CodeDOM examples that handle security are tricky to google.  After several hours of reading I have found two approaches.

The best seems to be the **Managed Addin Framework** because it is designed for exactly your use case senario. 
[Restrict plug-in assembly code access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520113/restrict-plug-in-assembly-code-access)

**CAS (Code Access Security)** is also an option but it appears to be less popular and on the way out.  Here is an example lifted from this [SO post][3]

```
var myEvidence = new Evidence(new object[] {SecurityZone.Internet});
var newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("InternetDomain");
myDomain.Load("MyUntrustedAssembly.dll", myEvidence);
myDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("MyUntrustedAssembly","MyUntrustedObjectType");
```

CAS References
[.NET/Security: Limiting runtime-loaded assemblies from accessing certain APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807069/net-security-limiting-runtime-loaded-assemblies-from-accessing-certain-apis)
http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=418038
http://www.go4answers.com/Example/codedom-security-64586.aspx